# Why is Git in VS2019 trying to create / access files on non existent Y: drive?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2019

I'm getting a strange set of errors, using Visual Studio 2019 and git on a newly-ish refreshed installation of Win 10. I did the refresh where my User folder is not deleted, but windows is reinstalled so I had to reinstall all my apps. Don't know if that's relevant tho.

Anyway, now when I open a new solution / project in VS, one which has not been opened before (either newly cloned or just a location existing since before the refresh), I get the "Identify yourself to Git" popup, but filled out with the correct settings that VS already has. If I click ok, with the "save to git global" setting checked, I get an error "Could not create file Y:/.gitglobal" or similar.

Also when I push to a repo, I get the "Save RSA key for server" popup, but then I get an error in the Git output window in VS, with the error `Could not create directory '/y/.ssh' (Permission denied).`

Any ideas? When I run VS as administrator, neither of these errors happen, but I'd rather not have to run VS as admin, if I don't have to.

Comment: Have you checked your environment variables? Maybe there is a variable set for USER_HOME or similar, that points to this path.

Comment: Actually, I just realized that I indeed do have a Y: drive mapped, some network drive that IT must have added? It's weird that it's being used for this tho, I'd like it to not be.

Comment: Then most likely it's indeed an environment variable, i had a similar behaviour in a previous company

Comment: I don't see any Environment variable with Y: or anything like this drive path in it, at least not in the "System Properties -> Environment Variables" way of seeing them, I'll try command line or something

Comment: Yes, in powershell I find "HOMEDRIVE                      Y:" environment variable... boo! I need to delete that

Comment: Is it possible to see where an environment variable comes from?

Comment: I don't think so, but you might get better answers for that specific topic over at superuser.com

Answer (score 0):

Turns out our IT guy was ambitious and pushed a Group Policy update that changed these `HOMEDRIVE` and `HOMEPATH` variables on my machine. He has now reverted the policy change, I had to do in terminal: `gpupdate /force` and reboot my computer. After that, `HOMEDRIVE` and `HOMEPATH` are back to the correct regular `C:` and `/Users/username`.

I was unable to change these "environment variables" using any command like `set` or something like powershell `[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable(bla)` since I guess they weren't "real" environment variables? At least I could not find them in the registry paths usually associated with environment variables.